# Is $h:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$,where $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be differentiable functions. Does it imply that $h:\mathbb{R}^m\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$,where $h(x,y)=(f(x),g(y))$ differentiable? Explain why.

So, I think it is true. Since $f,g$ are are differentiable their partial derivatives exist. But it is not suffices to prove the differentiability of $h$. Can somebody please explain me how to solve this? Or am I wrong? I mean, can I disprove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be differentiable, and in blocks, we'll have $$Dh(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix} Df(x) & 0 \\ 0 & Dg(y)\end{bmatrix},$$where these $0$' are blocks with the adequate sizes. Let's check: \begin{align}\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} &\frac{h(x+h,y+k)-h(x,y) - (Df(x)(h),Dg(y)(k))}{\|(h,k)\|} = \\ &=\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{(f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)(h),g(y+k)-g(y)-Dg(y)(k))}{\|(h,k)\|} \\ &= \left(\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)(h)}{\|(h,k)\|}, \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{g(y+k)-g(y)-Dg(y)(k)}{\|(h,k)\|}\right)\\ &= (0,0).\end{align}

Comment: don't you need $\vert \vert \cdot \vert \vert$ in the numerator?

Comment: Not quite. We have that ${\rm stuff} \to 0$ if and only if $\|{\rm stuff}\| \to 0$, so we're good.

Comment: I thought the $meaning$ of $stuff \to 0$ was $\|{\rm stuff-0}\| \to 0.Don't you have to say it? At least in the first line, where you are checking $Dh$. All the defs of derivatives I have seen go like this: $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left \| f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h \right \|}{\left \| h \right \|}$

Comment: I thought the $meaning$ of stuff$\to 0$ was $\left \| \text{stuff }-0\right \|\to 0 $. All the definitions go like this $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left \| f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h \right \|}{\left \| h \right \|}$.So you need to start here, at least n the first line when you begin the check on $Dh(x)$.

Comment: It is equivalent to what I have used. I shouldn't have been lazy and just wrote that \begin{align}\lim_{h \to 0} {\rm stuff}(h) &= 0 \\ \lim_{\|h\| \to 0}{\rm stuff}(h) &= 0 \\    \lim_{h \to 0} \|{\rm stuff}(h)\| &= 0 \\ \lim_{\|h\| \to 0} \|{\rm stuff}(h)\| &= 0\end{align} are all equivalent.